# How can I make a program on python that connects a raspberry pi to a windows PC and allows the two to communicate?

Tags: python, linux, raspberry-pi, network-programming

I currently have no ideas for what code I could use, nor if it is even possible but I have been asked to find out for work. I work for a broadcasting company and they have bought a raspberry pi as a experimental thing. They want to use it to attach to monitors and screens at festivals and other jobs they do. None of the other workers here even have the slightest idea how to work python 3 so its up to me to get a network set up between a windows 7 home premium pc and their raspberry pi. I have looked at some Youtube videos of various people trying to do this but each one says something different and it has confused me further. Please get back to me if anyone has a definitive answer. Thank you

Comment: Communicate *what*? What are the two systems supposed to "talk about"? Stream videos from a central location? If you can do that on any "normal" Linux PC then you can do it on an R-Pi too.

Comment: Actually, you might not even have to do any programming to get it to work, just have a meadiaplayer program (like e.g. VLC) stream from the server and display on the screen connected to the R-Pi. Just make sure the stream is in a format that be decoded by the R-Pi hardware.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Connecting to computers for communication has nothing to do with Python. Instead, you might want to look into SSH clients for windows and how to setup the corresponding server on the Raspberry (which will certainly run a Unix system). Everything else depends on the specific application.

Here is a tutorial on SSH using Windows: https://www.raspberrypi.org/documentation/remote-access/ssh/windows.md

You basically install PuTTY, log into your Raspberry and control it via command line (create and manipulate files etc.) as if you were working on the Raspberry directly.

Comment: Is there a way I can use the putty to send video file or graphics to the raspberry pi?